# Are Postgres WHERE clauses run sequentially?

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking at using Postgres as a database to let our clients segment their customers.

The idea is that they can select a bunch of conditions in our front-end admin, and these conditions will get mapped to a SQL query. Right now, I'm thinking the best structure could be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users

WHERE id IN (
  -- condition 1
)

AND id IN (
  -- condition 2
)

AND id IN (
  -- etc
)
```

Efficiency and query speed is super important to us, and I'm wondering if this is the best way of structuring things. When going through each of the `WHERE` clauses, will Postgres pass the `id` values from one to the next?

The ideal scenario would be, for a group of 1m users:

- Query 1 filters down to 100k
- Query 2 filters down from 100k to 10k
- Query 3 filters down to 10k to 5k

As opposed to:

- Query 1 filters from 1m to 100k
- Query 2 filters down from 1m to 50k
- Query 3 filters down from 1m to 80k
- The intersection of all queries are mashed together, to 5k

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here, I'd love to get your thoughts!

Thanks!

Comment: If efficiency is important to you, don't use big `IN` lists. Use `EXISTS (...)` subqueries or joins.

Comment: Also, TL;DR answer for the question: "no"

Answer (score 1):

Postgres uses a query planner to figure out how to most efficiently apply your query.  It may reorder things or change how certain query operations (such as joins) are implemented, based on statistical information periodically collected in the background.

To determine how the query planner will structure a given query, stick EXPLAIN in front of it:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT id FROM users ...;
```

This will output the query plan for that query.  Note that an empty table may get a totally different query plan from a table with (say) 10,000 rows, so be sure to test on real(istic) data.

Comment: and of course `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` if you want timing and rowcounts

Answer (score 1):

Database engines are much more sophisticated than that.

The specific order of the conditions should not matter. They will take your query as a whole and try to figure out the best way to get the data according to all the conditions you specified, the indexes that each table has, the amount of records each condition will filter out, etc.

If you want to get an idea of how your query will actually be solved you can ask the engine to "explain" it for you: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

However, please note that there is a lot of technical background on how DB engines actually work in order to understand what that explanation means.